# adding users points to db

Tags: php, addition, points

I did search this but can't find any thing or I'm blind.

I'm trying to add points for ever users I use update, but it keeps changing the points: for exp:

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET points='20' WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'")
```

It adds 20 points but when I submit It again It stays the same.

Any help would be great.

Comment: `set points=points+20`

Comment: btw you need to `mysql_real_escape_string()` the user name

Comment: It stays the same because you `SET points = 20`. Why else would it change?

Comment: @Pekka웃 - `mysql_*`? One of these days the switch will happen... `:P`

Comment: @Thanks you so much :), and also yes i was going to use : mysql_real_escape_string()mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: @Jarred http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143382/138112

Comment: @Pekka웃 - Whose this *Jarred* fella?

Comment: @Jared Farrish - yes i know it's not how you do it, i did try something like points=20+ .

Comment: @Jared a user on this programming site I visit regularly. Shifty-looking guy! Red hair, weird mustache...

Comment: @Pekka웃 - I'll make sure and keep a safe distance. He probably runs with a certain Colonel.

Comment: @Jared that sounds like a good idea. You can't be careful enough these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should probably be `points=points+20`

Comment: as @Pekka 웃 said, but Thank You :)